# Laravel 5.2 - How to render page before all content load

Tags: php, laravel, caching, optimization

I've another question about Laravel.

I've got gallery in my project which loads a lot of images (currently it's about 80 but it will still grow). The way I'm loading images is easy - in controller I get all the records from `photos` table and just passing them to view. In view I have `foreach` loop which shows every image.

The problem is that Laravel is probably caching the rendered page and then loads it. It causes gallery page long lasting loading (now between 5-10 sec depends on server load).

Am I right that it firstly caches the rendered page and then loads it? Will using faster caching package solve the problem?
Or is there any other way to speed up site loading?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: While I am not sure exactly what step in the process laravel loads the page, galleries are something that are easily powered by caching systems like redis. I advise you to take a look at it. The way I usually work is using scored sets to score newest based on time stamps and than use hashed sets to store info about the images in the gallery. Laravel has redis libraries already baked in: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/redis. Just be sure to add the predis/predis package via composer and check out their documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want goes beyond Laravel and the slow load time is due to the amount of time it takes for the client to download the images. (Unless of course you are sending the images in base64 which would be quite strange in this case.)

Here is how others have solved this problem:

- Create thumbnails for all the images and full size images are viewed after a thumbnail link is clicked.
- Use a JavaScript to load the images.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, this is the way it's currently done. I've got thumbnails (but they are quite big since they are 4 in one row) and there are links to the full resolution images. However, I have rewritten this site from cakephp and there was no problem - images were loading "realtime", not before rendering.

Comment: I have changed the quality of thumbnails. Now ~80 images takes 1.64 MB and it still takes ~5 sec to load page.

Comment: Finally found the reason of long loading - plugin for images was performing it's actions really long. I changed "getting" width and height to static and page loads immediately ;)